# the http request to the remote web driver server for url selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using c# with selenium web driver (4.8.2), Web driver manager (2.16.2) and Chrome Browser (118). and This is my code to initialize the browser to start the test:

```
new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);

var options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");   
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);

options.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=0");

options.AddArguments("--headless");

options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");

options.AddArguments("--window-size=1280,800");

options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");

options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");

Statics.Driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));

Statics.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
```

But sometimes I got the following error:
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51122/session/6f95462841136a5212e606fe741724fd/element/86BF94BB6EF686852725954F6F12C948_element_6/click timed out after 180 seconds.

Is there any root solution for this error.

Comment: You have the timeout at 3 minutes. Make it larger : TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)  The time to download will vary depending on lots of factors.  Since it works some of the time the solution is to make the timeout larger.